# elasticsearch - create TransportClient singleton instance

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a singleton instance of client for multiple index creation. Below is the code for the same. But every time I'm getting instance as null and it's creating a new instance. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong

singleton instance :

```
public class ESClientSingleton {

    public static Client instance ;

    private ESClientSingleton()
    {}

    public static Client getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
          {
            System.out.println("the instance is null...");
            ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder(); 
                    settings.put("node.client", true); 
                    settings.put("node.data", false); 
                    settings.put("node.name", "node-client");
                    settings.put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch");
                    settings.build(); 
            instance = new TransportClient(settings)
                            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("10.203.251.142", 9300));
            //instance = client;
            System.out.println("return the client");
            return instance;
          }
        return instance;
    }       
}
```

calling method :

```
public static IndexResponse insertESDocument(String nodeName, String json) throws MasterNotDiscoveredException, SocketException
  {  
      Client client = ESClientSingleton.getInstance();
      logger.debug("calling the es client");
      logger.debug("the json received as == "+json);
      IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("aricloud-nodes","node-entry",nodeName )
                               .setSource(json)
                               .execute()
                               .actionGet();
      logger.debug("the document is successfully indexed...");
              System.out.println("the document is indexed...");
              //client.close();
      return response;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the correct way to call the singleton client object instance for elasticsearch cluster. I had some issue with webapp and the same is working now.

Nevertheless this can be an example for someone who are looking for similar kind of answer.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing Singleton pattern, use **enum** instead of a class. 
enum has many built in advantages which helps us to simplify the singleton implementation.
Refer joshua bloch's Effective Java for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-threaded environment, checking if the instance is null might not be enough.

You can have a **racing condition** with 2 or more threads that are doing this check in parallel, and the second will try also try to instantiate the object because the first didn't finish the assignation.
There are many ways to overcome this, most common would be to declare instance as **volatile** and to put the if in a **synchronized block**:

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static volatile SingletonDemo instance;
    private SingletonDemo() { }
    public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
        if (instance == null ) {
            synchronized (SingletonDemo.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new SingletonDemo();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Or the enum solution, as proposed by Jayan K.
More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern